# How to remove repeated entries from an array while preserving non-consecutive duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like `var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5];` I really want the output to be `[5,2,9,4,5]`. My logic for this was:

- Go through all the element one by one.
- If the element is the same as the prev element, count the element and do something like `newA = arr.slice(i, count)`
- New array should be filled with just identical elements.
- For my example input, the first 3 elements are identical so `newA` will be like `arr.slice(0, 3)` and `newB` will be `arr.slice(3,5)` and so on.

I tried to turn this into the following code:

```
function identical(array){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++){
        if(array[i] == array[i + 1]){
            count++;
            // temp = array.slice(i)
        }else{
            count == 0;
        }
    }
    console.log(count);
}
identical(arr);
```

I am having problems figuring out how to output an element that represents a group of element that are identical in an array. If the element isn't identical it should be outputted in the order that it is in in the original array.

Comment: Can you maybe give a http://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Why are you slicing the array?

Comment: What do you mean with "output an element that represents a group of element"? You can easily remove repetitions but what does this have to do with "output"? Maybe you want a data structure that keeps track of the repetitions albeit the original array is reduced?

Comment: so what expected output:`[5,2,9,4,5]` or `[[5, 5, 5], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 9, 4, [5, 5, 5]]` or something else?

Comment: @Grundy [5,2,9,4,5]... i wanted to slice because i didnt know how else to split up the sections  that are identical so i could get the number

Comment: I like these answers. I'm going to need some time to go over them before i accept one. Thanks guys

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using [`array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter) you can check if each element is the same as the one before it.

Something like this:

```js
var a = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5];

var b = a.filter(function(item, pos, arr){
  // Always keep the 0th element as there is nothing before it
  // Then check if each element is different than the one before it
  return pos === 0 || item !== arr[pos-1];
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = b.join(', ');
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: im not sure about the return statement. your setting the index `pos`  on the left side to 0. On the right side your checking to see if the item is not equal to arr[0-1] for the first iteration then iterating through the array [1-1], [2-1]  etc. with the filter method? this is a lil too advanced for me. i think arr[-1] is undefined.

Comment: @user2537537: I'm not setting anything.  `pos === 0` is a comparison.  It's checking if `pos` is equal to `0`.  If it is, it adds it to the new array.  (It assumes `0` should be in the new array because `arr[-1]` is undefined.)  If `pos` is greater than `0`, then the other side of the `OR` (`||`) statement is evaluated.  `item !== arr[pos-1]` checks if the current item in the array is different from the previous one.  If it is, then it's added to the new array, otherwise it's skipped.

Comment: `a.filter()` iterates over each element and runs the callback.  It passes the callback function the value of the element, its index (and the entire array) as the parameters to the callback.

Answer (score 4):

if you are looking purely by algorithm without using any function

```
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5];

    function identical(array){

        var newArray = [];
        newArray.push(array[0]);
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length -1; i++) {
            if(array[i] != array[i + 1]) {
                newArray.push(array[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        console.log(newArray);
    }
    identical(arr);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3218n38p/1/);

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5];

var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  if (acc.prev !== cur) {
    acc.result.push(cur);
    acc.prev = cur;
  }
  return acc;
}, {
  result: []
}).result;


document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit hackey, but, hell, I like it.

```
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5];
var arr2 = arr.join().replace(/(.),(?=\1)/g, '').split(',');
```

Gives you

```
[5,2,9,4,5]
```

Admittedly this will fall down if you're using sub-strings of more than one character, but as long as that's not the case, this should work fine.

Comment: Maybe if you replace `(.)` with `(^,)+` (match all but a comma) it should also work with multi-character matches and sub-strings. Don't really know until I test it but I'm too lazy right now :)

Comment: Gotta love unexplained downvotes. @pid - maybe you're right, I'm a bit lazy to check.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for the job. Your one liner is by far the hardest to understand. In this simple example, it seems to be only [about half as fast](http://jsperf.com/array-filter-vs-regex) - with the askers shorter 13 element input array, it still clocks in at 75% slower than the most simple array scan posted by @Amit.rk3. Tested with Firefox 38 and Chrome 43; curiously, the filter is slower than the regex on Firefox, but the forloop consistently beats all others by a wide margin.

Comment: Perhaps you missed my proviso: "A bit hackey, but, hell, I like it." I never said it was the optimum solution, merely "a" solution, so chill.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var a = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4, 5, 5, 5];

uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
});
```

See [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Comment: Not quite.  This will result in `[5, 2, 9, 4]`.  The OP wanted to only remove "local" duplicates to get a result of `[5, 2, 9, 4, 5]`.